# When I try to upload an image to AWS S3 through axios, a network error occurs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, amazon-s3, next.js, axios

Below is the code that sends a put request to s3 using the pre-signed URL I received from our server.

```js
  axios.put(res.data.preSignedUrl, photo, {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": photo.type
    }
  }).then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
  })
```

`photo` is the image file I want to upload. We can guarantee that both the pre-signed url and the image are non-null.

[image]

I tried various methods, such as sending an image file to `formData` or changing it to the `fetch` method, but it did not help. I have no idea what the cause is... If you need any more information, please ask. Thanks for your help.

The version of axios is v.1.6.2.